# How do you say “anyway” in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary

Using ‘anyway’ to indicate that the previous matter was an aside, or it doesn’t affect the conclusion, for instance, to say: “It was wet and nobody was at the park. Anyway, I went home.”

Answer (score 10):

One option is *ceterum*, used famously by (some who paraphrase) Cato:

> ***Ceterum** censeo Carthaginem esse delendam.*
> **Anyway**, I think Carthage should be destroyed.

Some would translate it as "furthermore" or "moreover" here, but "anyway" works too.

Comment: "Anyway" implies Cato was saying in effect - "What I've just said [in our debate about whatever topic] is less important however, than the important issue for Rome - that Carthage should be destroyed."  As opposed to furthermore - , "Since I'm speaking I'll also remind us that Carthage should be destroyed".  That works since OP specified "I went home" is the important point, but just curious, do we know if Cato thought that?

Comment: @lessthanideal I don't think we have any direct quotes from Cato on that. That's a good question and worth exploring, so I recommend asking a new question about (textual proof of) the nuance of Cato's invention with his repeated reminders.

Comment: thanks - asked now over on the History SE https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/64200/did-cato-the-elder-think-destruction-of-carthage-was-more-important-than-anythin

Comment: @lessthanideal That question would have been fine here as well, and without the anti-covid nonsense.

Comment: @cmw Didn't occur to me to ask it here, since in my mind the new qn is "what did this person in history think?".  Is Cato the only person we know used ceterum? If to us he 'owns' the word I'd agree more. I can't' find guidelines for what this site accepts just now. [to clarify for other readers, covid was in answer to my qn there, not my qn]

Answer (score 4):

**Utique**.

As Lewis and Short say, *utique* means, "in any case, at any rate, certainly, surely, assuredly, by all means, particularly, especially, at least, without fail, undoubtedly, etc., = *certe*, *saltem*".

Answer (score 3):

Could you use *Tamen?* "Nevertheless/however" seem to have a bit more of a concessive feel to it, but I feel it works largely the same way. It has the effect of moving past whatever objection or interruption preceded it, which is basically how "anyway" works.

I feel both have the function of "getting back on topic."